# Using Arduino library in Processing and enabling internal pull-up resistor

Tags: arduino, processing, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am trying to made [this project](http://www.instructables.com/id/Pressure-Sensor-Matrix/) and using an Arduino library in Processing (Firmata) for serial communication. For this project, it requires a pull-up resistor, which Arduino analog pins also have, and need to be enabled with code. While I tried a lot of times it's still not working. I am wondering, is the Arduino library on processing capable for enable pull-up resistor? Has anyone done that before?

My sensor is connected to 5v on one end, and on the other is ground and A0.

I uploaded standardFirmata to Arduino. Here is my processing code:

```
import cc.arduino.*;
import org.firmata.*;
import processing.serial.*;

Arduino arduino;
int A1;
int A2;

void setup() {
  size(800, 500);
  arduino = new Arduino(this, Arduino.list()[1], 57600);
  arduino.pinMode(A1, Arduino.INPUT_PULLUP);
  arduino.pinMode(A2, Arduino.INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  stroke(0);
  if ((arduino.analogRead(A1) != 0) {
  rect(150, 100, 100, 300);
    fill(#BFA4E5);
  }
  if (arduino.analogRead(A2) != 0) {
  rect(250, 100, 100, 300);
    fill(#BFA4E5);
  }
}
```

Comment: Also asked at http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=500499

Answer (score 0):

You could enable your pull-up resistor with:

```
pinMode(pin, INPUT);        
digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
```